# Mac OS X Server unable to continue

Tags: macos, mac-mini, osx-server

When installing Mac OS X Server on a Mac mini Server with its original install DVD, the install is unable to continue from the first screen.

Can install other versions of MacOS without an issue, any pointers?

[image]

Comment: This looks rather ancient.  What model mini?  What version of OS X?  What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: Did you do a fresh download of the Server app from the AppStore?

Comment: @not2savvy This looks like the stand-alone version of OSX Server, not the addon available in the Store.

Comment: @Allan Mac mini Server Late 2009, Disc with it says Mac mini Mac OS X Server Install DVD 691-6520-A. Restore it to its original state

Comment: Is there a reason for needing this *particular* install version?

Comment: @Allan Its the original one it shipped with, as long as I get Mac OS X Server 10.6 back on it, hoped the original DVD with it would get me there. It does show as a bootable DVD and runs through all the motions until it reboots to proceed with the install

Comment: It looks as if the installation procedure stalls when trying to access some Apple site for verification purposes or similar. This may fail due to expired signatures or perhaps just because the Apple server now requires TLS 1.2 to connect, and I think I remember that the old Server app did not support TLS 1.2 yet. If possible, try to get an updated Server app or get it from the App Store.